# Laravel 4 Redirect with fragment url not working

Tags: php, laravel, fragment-identifier

I'm creating a web app using laravel 4. I'm having an issue with redirecting back to the previous page with a fragment identifier after a form submission. It just redirects slightly below the top of the page instead of to the specified location. How can I make this work?

here's my html:

```
<section id="name" class="row">
    <div class="large-4 large-centered medium-8 medium-centered columns">
        <h3 class="text-center white top-marg-2 bot-marg-2">{{{ trans('header.changeName') }}}</h3>
            {{ Form::open(['action' => 'AccountController@changeName']) }}
                @include('layout.form.first-name')
                @include('layout.form.last-name')
                @include('layout.form.submit')
            {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
</section>
```

the included files are my form fields.

This is my get route:

```
Route::get('account/edit', 'AccountController@getEditProfile');
```

This is my post route:

```
Route::post('account/name', 'AccountController@changeName');
```

This is my controller function:

```
public function changeName() {

    $validator  = UserValidate::Name(Input::all());
    $firstName  = Input::get('first_name');
    $lastName   = Input::get('last_name');

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        return Redirect::to("account/edit"."#name")->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

    } else {

        $user = User::find(Auth::id());
        $user->first_name = $firstName;
        $user->last_name = $lastName;
        $user->save();

        return Redirect::to("account/edit"."#name")
        ->with('success', trans('modals.account5'));
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had set "autofocus" on two form fields on two different forms on the page. That was the problem